# Add a dynamic supervisor to ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-otp

Is it possible to start a supervisor module in ejabberd which I can add a `gen_fsm` module to, per connection?

Specifically, I want to create a supervisor which I start when the server starts (or when connections come in).  And I have a couple of `gen_server`s which I want to start, but the part I'm looking for some guidance on is how to dynamically add a `gen_fsm` module to my supervisor when I see this user's presence become available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look to the [Simple one for on supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id71482), which:

> is a simplified one_for_one supervisor, where all child processes are
>   dynamically added instances of the same process
>
> ...
>
> When started, the supervisor will not start any child processes. Instead, all child
>   processes are added dynamically by calling:
>
> ```
> supervisor:start_child(Sup, List)
> ```
>
> ...

Basically, you use this kind of supervisors when:

1. All the children are of the same type
2. You want to add children dynamically

Which appears to be your case.

Comment: +1, also note that ejabberd does this already with some modules, including ejabberd_c2s